# SVG coordinates from Vector Art

Tags: vector, svg, coordinates

This may be impossible at the moment but I was wondering if it is at all possible to take a piece of vector art and run it through some sort of program that would translate it into SVG coordinates?

For instance lets say you have a logo as a jpg could a program map it precisely into SVG to be displayed on a website?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your vector design as an .SVG file, then open the .SVG file with a text editor of your preference and look for the "path" or "polygon" element. You should be able to locate an attribute called 'd' that holds the coordinates of your svg design. like so ...

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <path d="M0 0 ... ... ..."/>

</svg>
```

Depending on the complexity of your vector art the coordinates may range on how they are compiled and could be potentially hard to understand.

This url should help in understanding how the coordinates work -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Answer (score 2):

Most vector graphics editors include this feature (ability to trace a raster image).

There are also specialized tools such as [Vectormagic](http://vectormagic.com/) and a [whole slew of others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster_to_vector_conversion_software).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) has a *Trace bitmap* option that can be useful for that. Just import the file into Inkscape, and use that option to convert the bitmap to SVG. You may need some adjustments afterwards, but I think it can work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but what I eventually found was a jar file called SVG2Canvas.
Basically, (on a mac) you go through terminal and use their program to convert an svg file to cordinates inside the HTML5 canvas element.

Ive had mixed results but its a damn good start nonetheless.

The jar and (breif) documentation can be found here if you are at all interested.
http://code.google.com/p/lindenb/wiki/SVGToCanvas